# Network graph on all possible ways a letter/postcard can reach a person

Tags: r, igraph, sna

[image]I have a data frame in the following format. I want to make a network graph with all possible ways a letter/postcard can go from initial to final destination. Here is the dummy data.

```
postcard<- c('loveletter#234', 'loveletter#234', 'loveletter#234', 'officialletter#22','officialletter#22','officialletter#22','officialletter#22', 'newyearletter#24','newyearletter#24','newyearletter#24')
person<- c('Jane', 'Katie', 'Vince', 'John','Jane', 'Katie','Oliver','Katie','Becca','John')
df<- data.frame(postcard,person)
```

I want to create a network graph that shows the person as 'nodes' and the paths through which the post reaches the person as edges. For example, the graph should overlay the all the paths that occured in this transaction for 1) loveletter#234 2) officalletter#22 3)newyearletter#22 and superimpose. Can anyone suggest any ideas how to proceed this?

Thanks

Comment: The other question is going from one location to another. I have three cases and i need to overlay the three graphs over each other.

Comment: Can you unmark it as duplicate? It is not a duplicate.

Comment: Besides the fact it has insufficient data to complete the task, work requests are off-topic. Instead, describe what you tried and where you're stuck.